# Validate model using data annotation when doing AJAX call on form submission

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, model-validation

I have a problem with jquery ajax call on form submission.
As I don't want my page to be refreshed when submitting a form, I do e.preventDefault()

Unfortunately this causes all the client side model data annotation validation not to be displayed. It is very important to me to display all the model validation at a client side.

Does anyone know a way of doing so? If I prevented some default behavior, how do I turn on the validation? Any help would be appreciated

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('#basicForm');
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: form.action,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                // for testing
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `form.validate()`:

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('#basicForm');
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        form.validate();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: form.action,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                // for testing
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately form.validate() is undefined

Comment: $.validator.unobtrusive is undefined as well, but jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js are being loaded without problems. When I remove the e.preventDefault(), validation works fine

Comment: Ok, I've managed to have it defined. Though, the form.validate() returns number of properties, but it doesn't display them on the form as errors.

Comment: Try form.valid() instead. I think .validate() might literally just validate the form, whereas .valid() does the highlighting etc.

Comment: form.valid() returns info whether the model is valid (true/false), so it doesn't highlight any errors

Comment: Please could you post more of your code? I often use .valid() on input elements to do validation, so it should work.